# Implicit Converstion vs New

Tags: c#, implicit-conversion

I have the following class:

```
public class ChArray {
    private string m_str;
    public ChArray(string str) {
        m_str = (str.Length > m_len ? str.Substring(0, m_len) : str);
    }
    public static implicit operator ChArray(string str) {
        return new ChArray(str);
    }
}
```

I'm using this class as a dictionary key. Why are the following statements NOT equivalent? Using new, everything works just fine, but using a string, I get a key not found.

```
ChArray LINE_LEN = new ChArray("lineLen");
ChArray LINE_LEN = "lineLen"
```

The implicit operation returns a new ChArray, so why wouldn't this work?

Note that I'm not posting the full class to keep things simple. This DOES work if I use the new method.

Comment: Have you tried debugging?

Comment: post a code that compiles

Comment: @wudzik, yes. It fails when I try to access the dictionary.

Comment: @David I have created dotnet fiddle and it is working without dictionary here is fiddle link http://dotnetfiddle.net/xffvhJ

Comment: Please show a short but *complete* program. You haven't shown us how you're accessing the dictionary - nor any indication of overriding Equals/GetHashCode.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem is not in the code you've shown here.

The problem is that, if you want to use instances of a custom class as keys in a dictionary, you need to properly overload [`Equals` and `GetHashCode`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms173147.aspx).

As [LordTakkera](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1783619/lordtakkera) put it:

> The default comparer [for a class] will check if they are actually the same object (which of course they are not).

Note that:

```
Object.Equals("foo", "foo");   // returns true
```

But

```
Object.Equals(new ChArray("foo"), new ChArray("foo"));   // returns false
```

> A proper override of those two functions will provide the correct result.

---

This *should* work:

```
public class ChArray {
    // (as you have it)

    public override bool Equals(System.Object obj)
    {
        // If parameter cannot be cast to ChArray return false:
        ChArray p = obj as ChArray;
        if ((object)p == null)
        {
            return false;
        }

        // Return true if the fields match:
        return m_str == p.m_str;
    }

    public bool Equals(ChArrayp)
    {
        // Return true if the fields match:
        return m_str == p.m_str;
    }

    public override int GetHashCode()
    {
        return m_str.GetHashCode();
    }
}
```

Comment: The default comparer will check if they are actually the same object (which of course they are not). A proper override of those two functions will provide the correct result.

Comment: Thank you very much, especially for the code example. Out of curiosity, why does it need two Equals?

Comment: The overload of `Equals` that take a `ChArray` (space missing after class name) could check for `p` being `null`. Actually, when you have both overloads, the `object` version should be simply `return Equals(obj as ChArray);`, and the null check will happen in the specific overload. Consider implementing `IEquatable<ChArray>` since you chose to have this specific overload. Consider _either_ sealing the class _or_ checking for `GetType() == p.GetType()` in the specific overload.

Answer (score 1):

Maybe you need to override GetHashCode() and Equals() in your class ChArray ? These are used to compare keys.

Answer (score 1):

Just the addition to another answers. I mean, the question `Using new, everything works just fine, but using a string, I get a key not found.` still unanswered.

When you use

```
var key = new ChArray("lineLen");

dictionary.Add(key, someValue);
var value = dictionary[key];
```

the `key` still the same object and because you haven't overridden the `Equals` method the `object.Equals` used which is reference comparison.

When you use

```
ChArray key = "lineLen";

dictionary.Add(key, someValue);
var value = dictionary[key];
```

it is still must work.

but you will get `KeyNotFoundException` if you will use

```
ChArray key = "lineLen";

dictionary.Add(key, someValue);
var value = dictionary["lineLen"];
```

or

```
ChArray key = "lineLen";

dictionary.Add(key, someValue);
ChArray key1 = "lineLen";
var value = dictionary[key1];
```